# prove that there is no $\varphi \in C([0,1], \mathbb{R})$ such that $||\varphi|| = |L(\varphi)|$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Define the functional $L:C([0,1], \mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $L(\varphi) = \displaystyle\int_0^{1/2}\varphi(t)dt - \displaystyle\int_{1/2}^{1}\varphi(t)dt$. we consider in $C([0,1], \mathbb{R})$ the supremum norm. I have showed that $||L|| = 1$, however I couldn't show that there is no $\varphi \in C([0,1], \mathbb{R})$ such that $||\varphi|| = |L(\varphi)|$.

This exercise was proposed before the Hanh-Banach Theorem, so I don't know if you need this Theorem. Does anyone have any idea how to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $\varphi$ such that $\|\varphi\|_{\infty}=1$. Then, we see that
$$
\left|\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \varphi(t)\textrm{d}t\right|\leq \frac{1}{2}
$$
with equality if and only if $\varphi$ is constant and $|\varphi|\equiv 1$. Similarly for the other integral. Since $\varphi$ is continuous, if $\|\varphi\|_{\infty}=1$ and $|L(\varphi)|=1$ we get that there exists $e^{i\theta}\in S^1$ such that $\varphi(t)=e^{i\theta}$.

Then, however, we get that $L(\varphi)=0,$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: hello, thanks for responding. Can you enlighten me why this is true: that there exists $e^{i\theta}\in S^1$ such that $\varphi(t)=e^{i\theta}$? 
I think this would be true if $L$ were the integration operator from $0$ to $1$. Are you using any complex analysis results?

Comment: No. I'm just applying that very argument to the integral from $0$ to $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: So we get that there is $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ such that $\varphi(t)=e^{i\theta_1}$ for $t\in (0,1/2)$ and $\theta_2$ such that $\varphi(t)=e^{i\theta_2}$ for $t\in (1/2,1)$. However, we assumed that $\varphi$ is continuous. In particular, it's continuous at $t=1/2$ so $e^{i\theta_1}=e^{i\theta_2}$.

Comment: understood, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The only $L^\infty$ function with $|L(\varphi)|=||\varphi||$ is
$$
\varphi_1(x)=
\begin{cases} 
||\varphi_1||,& 0\leq x \leq 1/2 \\
-||\varphi_1||,&  1/2<x\leq 1
\end{cases}
$$
almost everywhere (and all constant multiples). Obviously, this function is not continuous.